# Issue when using itemssource to save and retrieve itemselected in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a template that fits in to a system that allows the user to complete a form. The issue that I am currently having is that the template I have created uses a dropdownbox that allows the user to select an int from a list that is pulled from a custom attribute on the question model. (I'm aware how horrible that sounds so it'll probably be easy to show via examples)

The two snippets below show the datatemplate for the dropdown question type. The first shows what I am hoping to achieve with the itemssource pulling through the dropdown options from the question and allowing them to be saved. But this is not working - it shows the options pulled through when the entry is clicked and they are then added to the box. After saving the page and reopening the previous selection is reverted to empty.

Questions.xaml - drop down template from itemssource(not working)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropdownTemplate">
     <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" HeightRequest="{Binding RowHeight}" Padding="{Binding IndentPadding}">
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Label Text="{Binding Text}" StyleClass="QuestionText"/>
                <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding Answer, Converter={StaticResource DropDownConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" StyleClass="QuestionAnswer" WidthRequest="100" ItemsSource="{Binding DropdownOptions}"></Picker>
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView StyleClass="ListBreak"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Questions.xaml - drop down template hardcoded (working)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropdownTemplate">
     <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" HeightRequest="{Binding RowHeight}" Padding="{Binding IndentPadding}">
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Label Text="{Binding Text}" StyleClass="QuestionText"/>
                <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding Answer, Converter={StaticResource DropDownConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" StyleClass="QuestionAnswer" WidthRequest="100" ItemsSource="{Binding DropdownOptions}">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                   <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:Int32}">
                      <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
                      <x:Int32>2</x:Int32>
                   </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView StyleClass="ListBreak"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
```

From debugging I can see that the clicking of the option and saving works as expected but upon reopening the page containing the newly saved entry the value goes into the converter correctly - is converted - and appears to have finished and worked as expected. The converter is then triggered again and the 'value' field is null which then sets the entry to null reversing the previous selection. (The hardcoded version works correctly accessing the converter as expected)

Drop down converter

```
public class DropDownConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            int final = Int32.Parse(value.ToString());
            return final;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string final = value.ToString();
            return final;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Question example (from model)

```
[QuestionAttribute(dropdownOptions = new List<int> ( 1, 2)]
[Display(Name = "QuestionName")]
public int? Question { get; set; }
```

QuestionAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class QuestionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int[] dropdownOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry if any of this is not clear I'd be happy to answer any more questions or provide images of the app if necessary. I am rather certain that the issue lies within the process of getting the itemssource from the question attribute of that particular question. Is there a better way to do this? Should it be held in a list?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Leon for the code you provided above. Apologies for my poor explanation of what I needed I have inherited this app from an external company and there is a lot going on that I was trying to cram into that question. I think my poor explanation and lack of any images showing what I had working led you down the wrong path. I will bare this in mind for next time and be sure to record what the app is doing at the time to help you along.

Irritatingly it appears to be a bug in xamarin that was causing my issue. [This link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98721/picker-setting-model-property-to-null-instead-of-setting-picker-selecteditem-to-value-in-model) here is the gist of it. For some strange reason re-ordering the properties inside the picker solves the issue.

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding DropdownOptions}" SelectedItem="{Binding Answer, Converter={StaticResource DropDownConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" StyleClass="QuestionAnswer" WidthRequest="100" >
```

What was essentially happening was that once my code (which behaves very similar to yours posted above) selects the value within a picker and then saves that value to the form. Upon exiting and re-entering said page the page attempts to fill the picker value with the one previously saved - having the picker properties in the order they were in previously meant the converter worked correctly (using convert to convert the value to an int and the convert back to return it to a string) before re-entering the convertback with null as the value therefore returning the picker to null and making my life a misery.

Many thanks for your help it helped me on my way!

Comment: You are welcome. Please do not forget to mark your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF.

[image]

I do not know specific `StyleClass` that you used. I delete all of them.

I used Mvvm to achieve that. you can refer to it.

First of all, here is layout.

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:DropDownConverter x:Key="DropDownConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <ListView Margin="0,20,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding myModels}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" HeightRequest="{Binding RowHeight}" Padding="{Binding IndentPadding}">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
                            <Picker  ItemsSource="{Binding DropdownOptions}" SelectedItem="{Binding Answer,Converter={StaticResource DropDownConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"  WidthRequest="100" ></Picker>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <BoxView />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
  public MainPage()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
 }
```

Here is my viewmodel.

```
     public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModels { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        myModels = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
        myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Answer=1, DropdownOptions= new int[]{ 1, 2 ,3, 4 }, IndentPadding=3, IsVisible=true, RowHeight=30, Text="test1" });
        myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Answer = 2, DropdownOptions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, IndentPadding = 3, IsVisible = true, RowHeight = 30, Text = "test2" });

        myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Answer = 1, DropdownOptions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, IndentPadding = 3, IsVisible = true, RowHeight = 30, Text = "test3" });
        myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Answer = 3, DropdownOptions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, IndentPadding = 3, IsVisible = true, RowHeight = 30, Text = "test4" });
        myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Answer = 2, DropdownOptions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, IndentPadding = 3, IsVisible = true, RowHeight = 30, Text = "test5" });

        myModels.Add(new MyModel() { Answer = 4, DropdownOptions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, IndentPadding = 3, IsVisible = true, RowHeight = 30, Text = "test6" });

}
}
```

Here is my model.

```
     public class MyModel
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public int RowHeight { get; set; }
    public int IndentPadding { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int[] DropdownOptions { get; set; }

    public int Answer { get; set; }
}
```